# Altering or disabling GRUB menu after failed boot of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 device that need to work all the time, but there are places with bad electric network, so there are regular electric shocks/shortages. Problem is that after failed boot/electric shock GRUB menu stays on screen for 30 seconds and so far I failed to change that with grub parameters. Here is my grub file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULY="fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="TRUE"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

This is the final version of the grub so far, and to note that i use "sudo update-grub". Another note is that I boot from sd card.

What I need to achieve is to reduce it to something like 5 seconds or skip it completely.

Comment: What do you see in the generated /boot/grub/grub.cfg file?

Comment: https://we.tl/t-K3TiBioqQe This is link to the cfg.

Comment: What is the date of both files? Is the whole system on a SD card or just the boot files?

Comment: The whole system is on SD card. The date is edit/update time. Just to make sure I updated again and their time do update.